# Access - Searching for a value

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to display a word in a field if another field displays something.

Say I have two fields called `[Fruit]` and `[Description]`

in `[Fruit]` would be
RApple
GApple

if `[Fruit]` states "RApple" I want the [Description] to read "Red Apple" - also would the `[Description]` save back to the table?

I have tried `IIf` and I can't get that to work.

I have the same thing working in Excel using ISNUMBER and SEARCH

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("RApple",B1)),"Red Apple",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("GApple",B1)),"Green Apple")
```

Can something like this work in Access?

Comment: Is the first letter always the color? I have two or three ideas depending on your answer.

Comment: It seems like `[Fruit]` stores 2 attributes in one field.  Are you locked in to that design choice?  It would be easier with each attribute in its own field.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if we were simply testing 2 strings and they were always in that format you provided, it could be as simple as :

`IIf([color] = "RApple", "Red Apple", IIf([color] = "GApple", "Green Apple", "No Match"))`

To search for the color :

`IIf(Left([Fruit],1)="R","Red",IIf(Left([Fruit],1)="G","Green","No Match"))`

This would all be better off in VBA, however given the context of your question, it doesn't sound like it's in scope, since this seems like a simple test.

I also agree with @HansUp in stating that this is a bad design with your data. When you can, you want to avoid prying logic out of strings. It would be much better with two fields: `[Color]` and `[Fruit]`. From there, you could make the string you so desire if you needed to (RApple, etc.)

Comment: Sorry, i've not had chance to check the answers out yet.  Hopefully I can check this today and come back to you. Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: I have checked the above code from @Invent - Animate - and this works!! but... It the description won't save in my table.  I have on my control source:-

'=IIf([Fruit]="RApple","Red Apple",IIf([Fruit]="GApple","Green Apple",IIf([Fruit]="YBan","Yellow Banana",IIf([Fruit]="Ora","Orange","No Match"))))'     any idea?

Comment: @Lee Your question didn't say anything about saving to a table. You should ask another question on the site so others may benefit if they are encountering the same problems you are, and it gives you the chance to explain exactly what you're trying to do. Otherwise we would need a lengthy discussion in the comments.

Comment: Hi @Invent - Animate - my question did state .... ' if [Fruit] states "RApple" I want the [Description] to read "Red Apple" - also would the [Description] save back to the table?'    Not a problem.  I will ask another question on the site.

Comment: @Lee well, if you could provide more details in your question around saving it I will certainly take a look, but I thought your main concern was getting the IIf to work